# Submaximal benching: are failed reps always controlled?

Tags: injury-prevention, bench-press

I saw a video of a guy catastrophically fail at benching and drop the bar from an almost locked position. I also learned that he later died of internal injuries. He even had 3 spotters, so I no longer consider spotters to be a reliable fail safe.

I guess I always knew this was a possibility if one fails in an uncontrolled manner, but I'd always assumed that when someone stalls they can just slowly lower the bar back to their chest, then do the "roll of shame".

The key difference between what he was doing and what I do is that I never max at bench. I always work in the 5 rep range. So my question is: how concerned do I need to be about catastrophically failing like that in a submaximal rep range? Will one always be able to slowly lower a stalled lift in higher ranges or should one lift in a power rack if they want 100% safety?

Comment: The lifter in the accident was using false grip. Thumbless grip has its risks.

Comment: mizo, I didn't notice that. It does make more sense once you know that. But it's not impossible for it to happen with a normal grip. A friend of mine had a thumb dislocate while benching with similar result. Luckily, the weight was a lot less and he only suffered bruised ribs.

Comment: safety stands FTW. I suppose human spotters are only good for assisted unracking and forced reps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I saw a video of a guy catastrophically fail at benching and drop the bar from an almost locked position

I saw it too. He had a thumbless grip. Wrap your thumbs.

> He even had 3 spotters, so I no longer consider spotters to be a reliable fail safe.

The job of the spotter is not to catch the bar when you drop it from a high place. The job of the spotter is to help you get the weight back up if you fail a rep. You still do most of the pushing, and the spotter does that last bit that gets the bar up. They're not responsible for your life.

> The key difference between what he was doing and what I do is that I never max at bench. I always work in the 5 rep range

That's a max too. If you're working at your highest possible 5-rep max, then the last rep of each set should be as hard to finish as your 1RM, and so you have the same problem.

> So my question is: how concerned do I need to be about catastrophically failing like that in a submaximal rep range? Will one always be able to slowly lower a stalled lift in higher ranges or should one lift in a power rack if they want 100% safety?

You shouldn't have to be worried, because you should have a spotter whenever you attempt a set that you know will have some hard-to-perform reps. Either that, or a safety cage to catch the bar.

Don't discount spotters just because you saw that one video where they weren't able to catch the weight, because that's not their job.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tough question to answer.  It depends on many **individual** factors, for example, fatigue as one.  There's nothing wrong with using a power rack if you are not 100% confident of making a lift.  I wouldn't rely on it all the time though.  Additionally, although it tends to get a bad rep (no pun intended), the Smith machine can afford a sense of security as well.

Comment: Why not rely on safety pins all the time? What added benefit is there to bench without them?

Comment: @mizo I would not recommend using "safety pins" all the time.  As my answer indicated there are appropriate times to use safety equipment.  However, using them all the time creates a false sense of security, and, does not allow supporting muscle and tissue to respond to the weight load.  They also tend to interfere with range of motion.

Comment: I don't see a problem using it below the chest. Since you should have an arch and your chest be higher than normal. I just use it in case of emergencies as I don't always have a spotter. Safety pins allow you to go for that last rep when you're uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

I think that as you start to get in the really high weights things can get dicey, but short of having an injury mid-lift (which can happen) you should be able to lower even a 1 rep max weight down to your chest.  That being said, you should know how to dump weights to the side on bench press.  If you don't use clips, you can just tilt the bar to the side and all the plates will slide off.